# Haskell: find subsets of list that add up to given number

Tags: haskell

I am working through some examples and trying to implement a function that counts how many subsets of a list add up to a given number.

In trying to rewrite some implementations in python to Haskell :

```
test1 :: [Int]
test1 = [2,4,6,10,1,4,5,6,7,8]

countSets1 total input = length [n | n <- subsets $ sort input, sum n == total]
  where
    subsets []  = [[]]
    subsets (x:xs) = map (x:) (subsets xs) ++ subsets xs


countSets2 total input = go (reverse . sort $ input) total
  where
    go [] _ = 0
    go (x:xs) t
      | t == 0 = 1
      | t < 0  = 0
      | t < x  = go xs t
      | otherwise  = go xs (t - x) + go xs t


countSets3 total input = go (sort input) total (length input - 1)
  where
  go xxs t i
    | t == 0         = 1
    | t < 0          = 0
    | i < 0          = 0
    | t < (xxs !! i) = go xxs t (i-1)
    | otherwise      = go xxs (t - (xxs !! i)) (i-1) + go xxs t (i-1)
```

I can't figure out why `countSets2` does not return the same result as `countSets3` (a copy of the python version)

```
λ: countSets1 16 test1
24
λ: countSets2 16 test1
13
λ: countSets3 16 test1
24
```

EDIT:
@freestyle pointed out that the order of my conditions was different in the two solutions:

```
countSets2 total input = go (sortBy (flip compare) input) total
  where
    go _  0 = 1
    go [] _ = 0
    go (x:xs) t
      | t < 0  = 0
      | t < x  = go xs t
      | otherwise  = go xs (t - x) + go xs t
```

fixes the problem.

Comment: I really like countSets1. That said, I get a count of 22 with `nub` in `length $ filter ((==16).sum) . nub $ subsequences [2,4,6,10,1,4,5,6,7,8]` and 24 without `nub`. One repeat is [2,6,1,7] and [2,1,6,7]. I think 22. `subsequences` and `nub` are imported from Data.List. `nub` is a *"set"* operations function. I like.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your logic, but in your second solution I think you need

```
go [] 0 = 1
```

otherwise, your code causes `go [] 0 = 0` which feels wrong.

Comment: I think need to add `go _ 0 = 1` in the beginning.

Comment: solution 2 is me trying to copy solution 3. The logic is that if the list is empty then there can't be any sub lists that add up to the number. It's the same as the `i < 0` check in the the third. If i is less than 0 the third one.

Comment: @freestyle yes that fixes the problem.  I thought I covered that case in the `| t == 0 = 1` part but I guess the order of checks is different in the two solutions I originally wrote...

Answer (score 0):

I don't treat your error so I don't expect you accept my answer. I only provide a solution:

```
import           Math.Combinat.Sets (sublists)

getSublists :: [Int] -> Int -> [[Int]]
getSublists list total = filter (\x -> sum x == total) (sublists list)

countSublists :: [Int] -> Int -> Int
countSublists list total = length $ getSublists list total
```

The module `Math.Combinat.Sets` is from the `combinat` package.

```
>>> countSublists [2,4,6,10,1,4,5,6,7,8] 16
24
```

Comment: is `sublists` not O(N²)? I don't see how this is better than my `countSets1`. Also, I am trying to work towards a solution that can use memoization.

Comment: @matthias I don't know. I never claimed it is better. It's just a simple solution thanks to `sublists`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem looks similar to [a pearl written by Richard Bird](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ZQJnYoAmw6gC&pg=PA33&lpg=PA33&dq=making+a+century+richard+bird&source=bl&ots=7B8AvHTyvD&sig=7kEEMYGI4t-ZyZCLZ-kgGJMdqDA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjihuzx95XaAhWCXMAKHfbJDJ0Q6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=making%20a%20century%20richard%20bird&f=false) on how many sums and products can make 100. I'll use it as a template here. First, the specification:

```
subseqn :: (Num a, Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Int
subseqn n = length . filter ((== n) . sum) . subseqs
```

where

```
subseqs = foldr prefix [[]]
prefix x xss = map (x:) xss ++ xss
```

Observe that a lot of work may be wasted in `subseqs`. Intuitively, we can discard candidates as soon as they exceed n, i.e. use the weaker predicate `(<= n)` somewhere. Trivially, filtering on it before filtering on the stronger one does not change the outcome. Then you can derive

```
filter ((== n) . sum) . subseqs
= {- insert weaker predicate -}
filter ((== n) . sum) . filter ((<= n) . sum) . subseqs
= {- definition of subseqs -}
filter ((== n) . sum) . filter ((<= n) . sum) . foldr prefix [[]]
= {- fusion law of foldr -}
filter ((== n) . sum) . foldr prefix' [[]]
```

The fusion law states that `f . foldr g a = foldr h b` iff

- f is strict
- f a = b
- f (g x y) = h x (f y)

Here, a = b = `[[]]`, f is `filter ((<= n) . sum)` and g is `prefix`.  You can derive h (i.e. `prefix'`) by observing that the predicate can be applied *before* prefixing:

```
filter ((<= n) . sum) (prefix x xss) = 
  filter ((<= n) . sum) (prefix x (filter ((<= n) . sum) xss))
```

which is exactly the third condition; then h is `filter ((<= n) . sum) . prefix`.

Another observation is that `sum` is computed too many times. To get around that, we can modify our definition of `subseqn` so that each candidate carries its own sum. Let's use

```
(&&&) :: (a -> b) -> (a -> c) -> a -> (b, c)
(&&&) f g x = (f x, g x)
```

and derive

```
filter ((== n) . sum) . subseqs
= {- use &&& -}
filter ((== n) . snd) . map (id &&& sum) . subseqs
= {- definition of subseqs -}
filter ((== n) . snd) . map (id &&& sum) . foldr prefix' [[]]
= {- fusion law of foldr -}
filter ((== n) . snd) . foldr prefix'' [[]]
```

I won't go through the whole derivation of `prefix''`, it is quite long. The gist is that you can avoid using `sum` at all by working on pairs, so that the sum is computed iteratively. Initially the sum is 0 for the empty list and all we have to do is add the new candidate to it.

We update our base case from `[[]]` to `[([], 0)]` and get:

```
prefix'' x = filter ((<= n) . snd) . uncurry zip . (prefix x *** add x) . unzip
```

where

```
(***) :: (a -> a') -> (b -> b') -> (a, b) -> (a', b')
(***) f g (x, y) = (f x, g y)
add :: Num a => a -> [a] -> [a]
add x xs = map (x+) xs ++ xs
```

Here is the final version:

```
subseqn :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> [a] -> Int
subseqn n = length . filter ((== n) . snd) . foldr expand [([], 0)]
  where
  expand x = filter ((<= n) . snd) . uncurry zip . (prefix x *** add x) . unzip
  prefix x xss = map (x:) xss ++ xss
  add x xs = map (x+) xs ++ xs
```

(`***` and `&&&` are from Control.Arrow)